# Mongoose: CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value “Object” at path “property”

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, objectid

I am getting the error:

```
CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "{ Type: 'Idea',
'Field/s of idea': 'cs',
Idea: 'cs',
Date: 2019-06-06T11:23:34.010Z }" at path "posts"
```

I am trying to update the property "posts" of a document with an object that do not contain a field for ObjectId. The document already has "_id" set to an ObjectId. I don't know why there is such an error when I am not trying to add an Object Id.
I searched for the error and the problems were only linked to '_id' property having a wrong ObjectId.

here is my code:

```
User.findOne({email: req.user.email})
        .then(user=>{
            if(user.posts){
                user.posts.push({
                        "Type": "Idea",
                        "Field/s of idea": req.body["Field/s of idea"],
                        "Idea": req.body.idea,
                        "Date": new Date()
                        });
            }else{
                user.posts = [{
                        "Type": "Idea",
                        "Field/s of idea": req.body["Field/s of idea"],
                        "Idea": req.body.idea,
                        "Date": new Date()
                        }];
            };
            console.log(user);
            user.save();
            res.send(user);
            console.log(req.user)
        })
        .catch(err=>{
            if(err)throw err;
        });
```

My schema code:

```
const UserSchema = new Schema({
    _id: {type: ObjectId, auto: true},
    username: {type: String, required: true, max:18},
    email: {type: String, required: true},
    password: {type: String, required: true, min:5},
    date_of_registration: {type: Date, required: true},
    posts: [ Schema.Types.ObjectId ]
}, { strict: false });
```

Comment: Your posts expect array of object ids, and not an array of objects.

Comment: Thank you, I wanted to put `[ Schema.Types.Mixed]` but I copied the wrong one. I feel dumb to not realize it.

Comment: Instead of `Mixed`, you should use Subdocuments, ref: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html

Comment: Thank you for the insight. I didn't know we could do such thing.